# Cannot save information to database - UNC share issue?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm attempting to save information to a local sqldatabase I've created to accept loss events for a process. However my issue at the moment is not an error message with regards to the code, but regarding the database itself I think. The error message box says, "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: [Database file location] failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located in a UNC share."
I have looked else where but nothing directly relates to my issue/or has worked.
Pulling my hair out now! Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

string constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=c: \\users\\user\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\LossApplication\\LossApplication\\LossDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True; ";

            string query=" insert into LossDB.LossTable (lossid,Equipment, Event, responsinility, start) values(@lossid, @equipment, @Cause, @reason, @start) ;";

            SqlConnection conLossDB = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdLossDB = new SqlCommand(query, conLossDB);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lossid", textBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Equipment", comboBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cause", comboBox2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", comboBox3.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", dateTimePicker1.Text);

            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conLossDB.Open();
                myReader = cmdLossDB.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Loss Entry Saved");
                conLossDB.Close();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection String,Use **Initial catalog** instead of **AttachDbFilename**

```
string constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
Initial Catalog = c: \users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LossApplication\LossApplication\LossDB.mdf;
Integrated Security=True; ";
```

Even i faced this issue,above code resolves.

Comment: Thanks that worked!
But now I'm getting a login issue, is this sorted by adding username password at the end of the connection string?

Comment: if this resolves,mark this as a answer.For login issue,if ur database is accessed only by credentials then you have to provide user id and password.